# IF statement in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I have the following SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
SELECT distinct  count (?Montreal) as ?Montreal count(?Toronto) as ?Toronto
WHERE
{
{?Montreal rdf:type yago:HospitalsInMontreal} UNION {?Toronto rdf:type yago:HospitalsInToronto}.
}
```

This query results in:

Montreal = 20
Toronto = 28

What I want is:
I want to edit the query and instead of giving 20 and 28, I want to compare the results such that 
If number of hospitals in Montreal is larger than the number of hospitals in Toronto then:

Montreal = 1
Toronto = 2

If the number of hospitals in Toronto is larger than the number of hospitals in Montreal then:

Montreal = 2
Toronto = 1

I tried this query but it didn't work:

```
PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
SELECT distinct  count (?Montreal) as ?Montreal count(?Toronto) as ?Toronto
WHERE
{
{?Montreal rdf:type yago:HospitalsInMontreal} UNION {?Toronto rdf:type yago:HospitalsInToronto}.
LET( ?Montreal := IF( ?Montreal > ?Toronto, -1, 1 ).
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no LET expression in SPARQL, but you don't need one for the above query:

```
PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT distinct if(count(?MontrealC)>count(?TorontoC),1,2) as ?Montreal if(count(?TorontoC)>count(?MontrealC),1,2) as ?Toronto 
WHERE
{
{?MontrealC rdf:type yago:HospitalsInMontreal} UNION {?TorontoC rdf:type yago:HospitalsInToronto}.
}
```

Comment: The new SPARQL 1.1 introduces BIND which is equivalent to LET in this case. Also, to be portable, your project expressions need parentheses around them: (if(count(?MontrealC)>count(?TorontoC),1,2) as ?Montreal)